__pch.h.slow/ fast file not found while using chisel simulation
I am using chisel-lang for my project. I use intelliJ IDE. While running the code I am getting
<command-line>: fatal error: VSeq1__pch.h.slow: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/usr/share/verilator/include/verilated.mk:275: VSeq1___024root__Slow.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

It has generated the .sv file but simulation is throwing error. How to rectify this error?
